# django-wsgiserver for cherrypy and django

Tags: django, cherrypy

I downloaded and installed django-wsgiserver app so i can use cherrypy with my django project. I used pip to install it and added it to my settings.py. I see the runwsgiserver command on my manage.py. But when i try to run it i get the following error

```
./manage.py runwsgiserver
KeyError: 'default'
```

What might be the fault? Do u need any more information?

```
setting.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_wsgiserver',
    'south',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

EDIT:I solved it...had to add db engine :P..But now i get this message

```
./manage.py runwsgiserver host=0.0.0.0 staticserve=False
Validating models..
0 errors found
October 06, 2013 - 11:02:37
Django version 1.5.4, using settings 'rhombus.settings'
cherrypy django_wsgiserver is running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.start_server_servestatic     of <django_wsgiserver.management.commands.runwsgiserver.Command object at 0x9f6c70c>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_wsgiserver/management/commands/runwsgiserver.py", line 469, in start_server_servestatic
    server.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_wsgiserver/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1857, in start
    raise socket.error(msg)
socket.error: No socket could be created
```

Why is this?

Comment: I found the solution....i didn't db engine set up...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are have a problem, before running ./manage.py runwsgiserver make sure that everything else works in your django project. For example, do::

./manage.py syncdb
./manage.py runserver  # to test out your project with the built-in server

The specific socket error you are seeing can occur if another process is running which has already used port 8000.

Also, I can see that you are using django 1.5.4. It always helps to mention which versions of the other applications and which operating system you are running on: linux?, mac?, windows? django-wsgiserver 0.8.0rc?

I hope everything is working now for you.

-CLM

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't use the django-wsgiserver after all. I only wanted the way to serve static. So I created an app like he describes and dispathced it on a cherrypy wsgiserver instance i created on a different python script. I tried the module too and it worked, probably runserver was still occupying my port